# Parsec parsing and separating different structures

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Let's say I have different parsers `p1, ..., pk`. I want to define a function `pk :: Parser ([t1], ..., [tk])` where `pi :: Parser ti`.

That will parse a collection of strings (one after the other) that match any of p<sub>1</sub>...p<sub>k</sub> and separate them in the corresponding lists. Assume for simplicity that none of the strings matches two parsers.

I managed to do it, but I am really struggling to find an elegant way (preferably using many or any other builtin parsec parser).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first step is to turn each of your parsers into parser of the big type:

```
p1 :: Parser t1
p2 :: Parser t2
p3 :: Parser t3
p1 = undefined
p2 = undefined
p3 = undefined

p1', p2', p3' :: Parser ([t1], [t2], [t3])
p1' = fmap (\x -> ([x], [], [])) p1
p2' = fmap (\x -> ([], [x], [])) p2
p3' = fmap (\x -> ([], [], [x])) p3
```

Now, we repeatedly choose from these last parsers, and concatenate the results at the end:

```
parser :: Parser ([t1], [t2], [t3])
parser = fmap mconcat . many . choice $ [p1', p2', p3']
```

There are `Monoid` instances for tuples up to size five; beyond that, you can either use nested tuples or a more appropriate data structure.

Comment: I think that's the closest it got get to elegance, luckily, my tuple has 5 elements :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Representing the parsers as a list makes this easy. Using:

```
choice :: [Parser a] -> Parser a
many :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
```

We can write:

```
combineParsers :: [Parser a] -> Parser [a]
combineParsers = many . choice
```

This isn't quite right, as it bundles them all into a single list. Let's associate each parser with a unique identifier:

```
combineParsers' :: [(k, Parser a)] -> Parser [(k, a)]
combineParsers' = many . choice . combine
  where combine = map (\(k,p) -> (,) k <$> p)
```

We can then convert this back to the list form:

```
combineParsers :: [Parser a] -> Parser [[a]]
combineParsers ps = map snd . sortBy fst <$> combineParsers' (zip [0..] ps)
```

You could perhaps make this more efficient by writing `combineParsers' :: [(k, Parser a)] -> Parser (Map k [a])` instead, using e.g. `combine = map $ \(k,p) -> fmap (\a -> Map.insertWith (++) k [a]) p`.

This requires that all the parsers have the same result type, so you'll need to wrap each of their results in a data-type with `Cons <$> p` for each *p*. You can then unwrap the constructor from each list. Admittedly, this is fairly ugly, but to do it heterogeneously with tuples would require even uglier type-class hacks.

There might be a simpler solution for your specific use-case, but this is the easiest way to do it generically that I can think of.

Comment: @Rotsor: Oops, fixed! Thanks.

Comment: I am still thinking about an elegant solution that avoids wrapping in a new type. Actually, my current solution is similar to what you suggest (except that it is hardcoded or instantiated to my types.. you made it abstract).

Comment: @aelguindy: Well, what's *k*? If it's more than, say, 3, you're probably doing something unidiomatic. Concrete details about your situation would help. Here's an example: parsing different kinds of definition in source code. It makes sense to have a single `Defn` type to represent all definitions, and to wrap up different kinds of definitions in constructors of those.

Comment: Well.. To be honest I am not very satisfied either. I don't want to do some type refactoring at the moment :-). In any case, I am still curious about the solution, be it useful or not.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this completely generically without type-level trickery, unfortunately. However, an approach along the lines of Daniel Wagner's suggestion can be constructed in DIY style, using polymorphic combinators and some pre-existing recursive instances. I'll present a simple example to demonstrate.

First, a few simpleminded parsers to test with:

```
type Parser = Parsec String ()

parseNumber :: Parser Int
parseNumber = read <$> many1 digit

parseBool :: Parser Bool
parseBool = string "yes" *> return True
        <|> string "no" *> return False

parseName :: Parser String
parseName = many1 letter
```

Next we create a "base case" type to mark the end of the possibilities, and give it a parser that always succeeds on no input.

```
data Nil = Nil deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Enum, Bounded)
instance Monoid Nil where 
    mempty = Nil
    mappend _ _ = Nil

parseNil :: Parser Nil
parseNil = return Nil
```

This is equivalent to `()`, of course--I'm only creating a new type to disambiguate in case we actually want to parse `()`. Next, the combinator that chains parsers together:

```
infixr 3 ?|>
(?|>) :: (Monoid b) => Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser ([a], b)
p1 ?|> p2 = ((,) <$> ((:[]) <$> p1) <*> pure mempty)
        <|> ((,) <$> pure [] <*> p2)
```

What's going on here is that `p1 ?|> p2` tries `p1`, and if it succeeds wraps that in a singleton list and fills in `mempty` for the second element of the tuple. If `p1` fails, if fills in an empty list and uses `p2` for the second element.

```
parseOne :: Parser ([Int], ([Bool], ([String], Nil)))
parseOne = parseNumber ?|> parseBool ?|> parseName ?|> parseNil
```

Combining parsers with the new combinator is simple, and the result type is pretty self-explanatory.

```
parseMulti :: Parser ([Int], ([Bool], ([String], Nil)))
parseMulti = mconcat <$> many1 (parseOne <* newline)
```

We're relying on the recursive `Monoid` instance for tuples and the usual instance for lists to combine multiple lines. Now, to show that it works, define a quick test:

```
runTest = parseTest parseMulti testInput

testInput = unlines [ "yes", "123", "acdf", "8", "no", "qq" ]
```

Which parses successfully as `Right ([123,8],([True,False],(["acdf","qq"],Nil)))`.

Comment: I think this is very elegant, although I still do not understand the definition of (?|>). I find it a bit overly complicated for the problem.. but still very elegant!

Comment: Why not use `()` instead of `Nil`? It already has a `Monoid` instance.

Comment: Actually, I think I understand it perfectly now! Great idea!

Comment: @ehird: Disambiguation, mostly. I like to be clear when I'm using something only as a sentinel or placeholder value, rather than simply using generic types. In fact, I'd probably be tempted to replace `(,)` as well, to make it clear that this is not actually parsing anything that looks like tuples.